# step jQuery and backgroundposition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new comer in jQuery. Is there anybody who could explain for me in detail what the following code means?

```js
$.extend($.fx.step, {
    backgroundPosition: function(fx) {
        // anything can be
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) that code add/merge/update a function to `$.fx.step` called `backgroundPosition`

Comment: I have this function and it is in charge of changing the background position.but I want to apply one function with same functionality , not for background position, but for changing the position of image.I mean img tag,is there a solution for doing that?I ask this question, because I have one img that I want to move it.any help will be appreciated,thank you

Comment: I think you are searching for [animation with jquery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) so you can change all the css attributes of your tag `img`

Comment: yes I was searching for that but now solved. anyway thanks for your help.
now I am facing with a confusion issue.I want to define one div above another div,but upper div should be visible if the height of lower div becomes less than size of screen.how can I manage this one??

Comment: till now no.to be honest I am so new comer in front-end development.I do not know , honestly from where I should start.this is a great issue.

Comment: i suggest to try few hours and then ask another question if you don't success